# How to do this with datetime & getpage in Python?

Tags: python

Currently having some problems-

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = now.strftime("%B")


site = wikipedia.getSite('en', 'wikiquote')
page = wikipedia.Page(site, u"Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day:abc")
```

I need to get abc to change into the name of the month before it then tries to get the page, yet everything I try it gives an error of some sort.

How could I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
page = wikipedia.Page(site, u"Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day:" + month)
```

Comment: Oh how easy it was!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The page URL format is actually [`Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day/Month`](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day/May). Try this:

```
page = wikipedia.Page(site, u"Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day/%s" % month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
page = wikipedia.Page(site, u"Wikiquote:Quote_of_the_day:%s" % month )
```